# Laravel - resolving uploaded image path

Tags: php, laravel

My uploaded images are located in `storage/app/spreferenceimages`

The image paths are stored in the DB in following manner:
`spreferenceimages/laravel-generated-filename.ext`

I am trying to use the path in my view. I tried `asset()` helper:

`<img src="{{ asset($spreference->favicon) }}">`

but it returns a `NotFoundException`. The generated url was:

`http://localhost:3000/spreferenceimages/v2hM7nJcSWdXCAh7RdJUR4CExAMQfk1XX0u4ZiX1.png`

How can I use the storage folder directly (Without having to generate a symlink in public folder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create route to access the file or upload the file directly to public folder

example using route:

```
Route::get('image/{path}', function(){
    return Storage::get($path);
})->name('image');

//acess the image
<img src="{{ route('image', $spreference->favicon) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [symbolic link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This creates a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` as the end user can access only what is in `storage/app/public`.

Then you can access the image:

```
http://localhost:3000/storage/v2hM7nJcSWdXCAh7RdJUR4CExAMQfk1XX0u4ZiX1.png
```